# Is there a way I can convert from an ArrayList to a HashMap in a for loop and get the same output?

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, for-loop, hash

I'm looking for a way to change this method from a for loop which iterates through an `ArrayList` to change to a `HashMap`.

```
public Card findCard(String cardName) {
    assert cardName != null;
    Card foundCard = null;

    if (allKnownCardsMap.containsKey(cardName)) {
        foundCard = allKnownCardsMap.get(cardName);
    }

    // for( Card cd :allKnownCards ) {
    //      if( cd.cardHasName( cardName ) ) {
    //          foundCard = cd ;
    //      }
    // }
    return foundCard;
}
```

The commented out code is the original and the top if statement is the one I have created, but I can't figure out as to why it is not giving the same result.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the initialization of the `ArrayList` and the initialization of your `HashMap` equivalent. If your map were keyed by card name and had the cards as values, the above would work (though it's more complicated than needed). So it sounds like there's a problem with how you're creating the map. (About "more complicated than needed": no need for the `if`, just use `Card foundCard = allKnownCardsMap.get(cardName);`. `get` returns `null` if not found.)

Comment: My blind shot would be that the problem is in `cardHasName` method and how you check if the name is equal. Are you comparing `String`s with `==` by any chance?

Comment: T.J thank you, im not sure why but when I took the if statement out it worked. I didnt know it wasnt needed.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your questions here - they will always be rolled back to the last good version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abit uncertain of the context as you already seem to to have a Map of some description in

> allKnownCardsMap

. But to convert an Arraylist to HashMap:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    myList.add("A");
    myList.add("B");

    for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
      myMap.put(i + 1, aList.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming allKnownCards is a list of type Card so first you need to change that list into map then you can perform any map operation so for that you can do something like here

```
Map<String, Card> allKnownCardsMap = allKnownCards.stream()
                                .collect( Collectors.toMap(Card::getName, 
                                        Function.identity()) );
```

Now you can have your code to check the name

```
if (allKnownCardsMap.containsKey(cardName)) {
        foundCard = allKnownCardsMap.get(cardName);
    }
```